# Como tratar a resposta JSON com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function($) {
    $('#enviaadv').submit(function() {
        //document.getElementById('btnConsultar').disabled = true; 
        $('div.mensagem-erro').html('');

        $(this).ajaxSubmit(function(resposta) {

            if (!resposta){
                $onclick = showadv('bottom','left',resposta);
            }
            else
            {
                $onclick = showadv('bottom','left',resposta);           
            }

        });

        return false;

    });
});
</script>
```

Estou recebendo dados JSON na `resposta` assim:

```
{"adv_nome":"Gabriel","adv_id":"8c7dac3ea415b863c8c8789b6667b2b1"}
```

Como posso tratar esses dados para pegar `adv_nome` e `adv_id`?

Comment: imagina que você quer jogar num `input`, seria assim: `$('#id_do_input').val(resposta.adv_nome);`

Comment: tentei fazer assim                  $nome.val(resposta.adv_nome);
      $onclick = showadv('bottom','left',nome); não deu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode acessar os valores de objeto [Json](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp) basta usar o (.) Para mais exemplos: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

```js
var resposta = {"adv_nome":"Gabriel","adv_id":"8c7dac3ea415b863c8c8789b6667b2b1"};
var x = resposta.adv_nome;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: ta dando undefined

Comment: eu devo trocar o json.name por resposta.name

Comment: @JoaoPedroPM Isso. Fiz uma alteração na resposta para condizer com seu código.

Comment: esta dando undefined

Comment: @JoaoPedroPM você usou  resposta.adv_nome ?

Comment: essa é a resposta exata que esta vindo do PHP

Comment: {"adv_nome":"Gabriel","adv_id":"8c7dac3ea415b863c8c8789b6667b2b1"}